# Que veut dire "impétrant"?

Tags: vocabulaire, noms, politique

J'entends depuis quelques jours un homme politique parler de ses [concurrents en ces termes](http://www.lemonde.fr/primaire-parti-socialiste/article/2011/10/12/arnaud-montebourg-dix-ans-d-union-et-de-desunions_1586035_1471072.html) :

> [...]des réponses que les deux candidats impétrants auront faites[...]

Que veut-il dire par *impétrant* ?

Comment: Dans le folklore estudiantin belge, un _impétrant_ est quelqu'un qui a demandé à passer sa [calotte](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Calotte_%28Belgique%29), mais ça ne s'applique sans doute pas à ton exemple.

Comment: @Joubarc : ça n'en n'est pas moins une variante intéressante ;) Le dialecte du monde étudiant mériterait presque un site à lui seul.

Comment: Pertinent : http://www.liberation.fr/politiques/01012365661-arnaud-montebourg-s-est-empetre-dans-le-mot-impetrant

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Un *impétrant* est de manière générale quelqu'un qui a été retenu lors d'un processus de sélection. On l'applique souvent pour désigner quelqu'un qui a été reçu à un examen. Le contexte est ici « les deux candidats impétrants », c'est-à-dire les deux candidats qui ont remporté le premier tour de l'élection.

(Pour les futurs visiteurs, le contexte est l'entre-deux-tours de la [primaire pour désigner le candidat du parti socialiste à l'élection présidentielle de 2012 en France](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primaire_pr%C3%A9sidentielle_socialiste_de_2011). Il s'agit d'une élection à deux tours, le second tour départageant entre les deux candidats les mieux placés au premier tour. L'homme politique est celui qui est arrivé troisième lors du premier tour.)

On trouve quelquefois le mot *impétrant* dans le sens de *candidat*, par confusion, mais ce n'est manifestement pas le cas ici vu l'expression « candidat impétrant ».

Answer (score 6):

En fonction du contexte, et [d'après le TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/imp%C3%A9trant), *impétrant* peut signifier :

> Celui (celle) qui a obtenu de l'autorité compétente ce qu'il (elle) avait sollicité (charge, titre, privilège)

ou encore :

> Celui (celle) qui a obtenu un diplôme universitaire

Dans le cas de la phrase donnée en exemple, on manque d'éléments contextuels pour en déterminer le sens. Les *candidats impétrants* peuvent tout aussi bien :

- être deux candidats au passage d'un diplôme ou d'une distinction (sens 2, donc)
- comme il peut s'agit de candidats à une élection et ayant tous deux demandé et obtenu quelque chose de l'administration ou d'une autre autorité (sens 1, en ce cas)

**EDIT, du fait de l'actualité**:

L'homme politique cité dans la question semble être M. Montebourg, et selon le linguiste Alain Rey, il n'aurait pas employé ce mot à bon escient.

Indépendamment des idées politiques véhiculées par le lien qui suit, on peut y trouver [l'analyse de M. Rey](http://www.liberation.fr/politiques/01012365661-arnaud-montebourg-s-est-empetre-dans-le-mot-impetrant).